# Python 3 - Creating a program inputing a list and printing the strings from it alphabetically

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm working a question where I need to create a program that will ask the user to input a list and then it will print off the strings that start with letters A-I.

Question: Implement a program that asks for a list of student names from 
the user and prints those names that start with letters A through I. 
Create two test lists.

```
>>> phrase = input('Enter a list of Students: ')
Enter a list of Students: ['Albert', 'Ian', 'Bob', 'Dave', 'Edward']:

>>> for c in phrase:
    if c in 'abcdefghiABCDEFGHI':
        print(c)
```

Right now the print function results in:

```
A
b
e
I
a
B
b
D
a
e
E
d
a
d
```

It prints off letters in each of the name in alphabetical order, but what I want it do do is print off the entire names in alphabetical order. Once I can do it for one list, a 2nd list shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Phrase here is a string, you haven't converted it yet to a list

Comment: Also its not doing what you think its doing, the output is clearly not alphabetical

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To only print out the names that start with those letters you just need to index the first character `c[0]`, e.g.:

```
phrase = input("Enter list of students")
for name in phrase:
    if name[0] in 'ABCDEFGHI':
        print(name)
```

Just be aware `input()` is generally considered unsafe because arbitrary code can be executed. A safer, but probably unnecessary at this level, approach would be:

```
import ast
phrase = ast.literal_eval(raw_input("Enter list of students"))
for name in phrase:
    if name[0] in 'ABCDEFGHI':
        print(name)
```

Comment: Thanks, this might be beyond what my teacher is expecting but I'll definitely keep this as a note.

Comment: Which bit do you believe is beyond? Happy to explain, e.g. `name[0]` means just the first character of the name `.upper()` makes it uppercase reducing the comparison list to just the uppercase `A-I`.

Comment: Well, beyond in what my teacher has taught us so far. Thats my first time seeing .upper() so far. I really appreciate your help. Nothing wrong with having more than 1 solution.

Comment: You don't have to use `.upper()` and could simply do: `if name[0] in 'abcdefghiABCDEFGHI':`

Comment: Good to know. Rereading the question I think its fine to go with 'ABCDEFGHI' and not actually worry about the uppercase, when I did this it was no problem printing off the names the way I wanted it to. Also, I don't think my teacher is expecting the names to be in alphabetical order, but simply just have them print based off the letters themselves.

Answer (score 0):

See my comment above, the phrase is a string when you input it. You have yet to make it into a list.

Try:

```
phrase = eval(input("Enter list of students")) #this evaluates the list put in
for names in phrase:
    for letters in names:
        if letters in 'abcdefghiABCDEFGHI':
              print(names)
```

Next up

```
phrase = eval(input("Enter list of students"))
i = 0
while i < len(phrase): #for each item in phrase up to the end!
      for letters in phrase[i]
           if letters in 'abcdefghiABCDEFGHI':
                  print phrase[i]
                  phrase.pop(i)
                  i-=1 #set i backwards (as the incrementer downstairs will set it back to normal"
                  break #get out of this loop only one print please

    i+=1 #fast way to increment
```

Comment: prints all names that contain any of those letters vs. just starts with.

Comment: This seems to work. I guess my only question now is it does print off several copies of the same name? For example, it prints "Edward" 4 times but shouldn't it only print it once since its the only name that starts with letter E?

Comment: Okay so there are two paths, one is if we print a name we can get rid of it from the list so it doesn't appear again. That requires a while loop as opposed to for loop as python *sigh* doesn't let you change the structure that you are 'for'-ing over.

Comment: The other option if you insist on using for loops is to keep a list that keeps track of whether something got printed and based on that makes a decision. i'll put up both

Comment: Thanks, I'm understanding it more than ever now. The problem is the lectures my teacher shows me did contain a lot of this but it only shows 1 step as opposed to multiple steps like you laid it out so its making a lot more sense.

Comment: `eval()` is unnecessary in Python3 as `input()` is already evaluated (`raw_input()` is the equivalent to Python2 `input()`)

Comment: Ah, well I guess that reveals my version number ;)